# MATLAB OOP : How do I call a method on an object of class A from inside a method in an object of class B?

Tags: oop, matlab

LANGUAGE:

I am writing an object-oriented code in MATLAB. I wrote almost all of it, and now when trying to test it, am running into what looks like a very fundamental issue.

BACKGROUND OF THE CODE:

I have a class Window and a class Tracker. Both are subclasses of the Singleton class (that is, they have private constructors to ensure that only one single instance of class Window and class Tracker are created).

I instantiate each of them- so I now have a myWindow and myTracker object.

In my main script, I call a method, myWindow.isNewbead(). isNewbead is a public method of class Window.

That's the scene. Now the problem:

THE PROBLEM:

Inside isNewbead(), I call myTracker.getpredictedPositions(). getpredictedPositions() is a public method of class Tracker. However, when I run this line, I get an error saying variable 'myTracker' is undefined. And sure enough, I look in the variable workspace, and the only variables there are the local variables INSIDE myWindow.isNewbead();

So I now have two questions:

QUESTIONS:

1. Is this true of OOP everywhere? That is to say, can you not call a public method on an object from inside a method in another object without explicitly passing the first object to the method of the second object? It seems like a lot of hassle to me, because I use properties and methods of lots of objects of different classes in every method, so I will have to end up passing hundreds of objects every time!
2. If this is only a MATLAB-specific problem (like the problem of no-static-variables) then how do I work my way around it?

Thank you so much!

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call a public method of one object (object A) from a method of another object (object B) since it's, well, public; however, you need to have a reference to object A to use within the object B method. Pass a reference to the object A as input argument to the object B method.

It may seem like a hassle but how else could this work? Even though Tracker inherits from the Singleton class, myTracker is still just an *instance* of the Tracker object. You need a reference to this instance in order to use its methods.

Comment: Hi b3, thank you so much for such a quick and clear response! Okay so what I take from this is the fact that there are static methods, but no 'static objects'. We absolutely need to pass references to objects we wish to use. But do good programs pass long lists of objects of different classes as arguments to methods in some other class? Isn't there a cleaner way of doing this? Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you need to pass a long list of objects as input arguments to a method, maybe that is an indication that you need to review the modularity of your method. Perhaps it would be better to divide the method into several methods. Alternatively, since you're dealing with a singleton class, would it be possible to have a property of the class which stores a reference to the constructed object which would be set in the constructor? That way a static method could use this property to operate on the one and only instance of this class.

Comment: Hmmm, ignore my second suggestion in the above comment. It wouldn't work as it relies on being able to update the value of a constant property in the constructor which isn't possible. Sorry.

Comment: If you're passing instance of a Singleton around, it's not a Singleton, it's just a class with one instance.  From Wikipedia (my GOF is 1500 miles away, sorry)  "Implementation of a singleton pattern must satisfy the single instance and global access principles. It requires *a mechanism to access the singleton class member without creating a class object* and a mechanism to persist the value of class members among class objects."  (emphasis added)

Comment: More conversation on this topic in the context of MATLAB can be found at: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/170056

Comment: @Marc : Requiring a mechanism to access a singleton class instance without creating a class object does not imply that the single instance cannot be passed around. However, if such a mechanism existed there would be little need to pass the instance around.

Comment: sounds like Q wants events and listeners http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/events-and-listeners-concepts.html;jsessionid=0a510870314e8cd010ae6e75e24b

Answer (score 3):

For a Singleton, the pattern requires "a mechanism to access the singleton class member without creating a class object ".  If you are passing around instance of the class, you've done it wrong.  Here is a Matlab implementation using static classes and the global appdata space.  There is [another implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24911-design-pattern-singleton-creational) with that does have an abstract parent from [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), but it will be deleted by `clear classes`.  Choose your poison.

```
classdef MySingleton < handle
%
%SingletonParent - A class to limit the instances created to one.
%
%There is a problem with matlab:
%   clear classes will clear just about any instance, even those stored in
%   persistent variables inside of functions.  This would close any opened singletons
%   To work around this, we have a method that creates an instance and assigns
%   it to the appdata structure.  This instance can be explicitly killed, but
%   clear all and clear classes will not kill it.  If you ever clear classes,
%   you will get several messages of this flavor:
%
%   Warning: Objects of 'MySingleton' class exist.  Cannot clear this
%   class or any of its super-classes.
%
%   because of the way we assign and store the singleton, you cannot make
% this an abstract parent
%
%   Also, any intialization must be done after you get the instance, since you
%   have to be able to create it without any data.
%

properties  (Constant)
    APP_DATA_NAME = 'MySingleton';
end %properties


methods (Access = private)
    function obj = MySingleton()
        %initialization code.
        %must be private to ensure getInstance call is the only link into it.
    end %Singleton
end%private methods


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
methods (Static)
    function out = getInstance()

    %getInstance - get/creates Singleton
    %
    %   stores the instnace such that it is immune to clear all/clear classes
    %
    %out = getInstance
    %Returns
    %   singleton instance.  if it does not exist, creates a default one, or passes the data to the ctor

    if ~isappdata(0, MySingleton.APP_DATA_NAME);
        obj = MySingleton;
        setappdata(0, MySingleton.APP_DATA_NAME, obj);
    end

    out = getappdata(0, MySingleton.APP_DATA_NAME);

    end %getMasterInstance()

end %static methods

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
methods
    %public methods that it uses to work.
end %PublicMethods



end %MySingleton Class
```